# What would the browser do with this html code: <img src="#"/>?

Tags: html

I was wondering what exactly would happen if you output `<img src="#"/>`?  Does the browser essentially try to submit the same URI twice?

Comment: Browsers use caching - based on many factors; and subtle differences just for good measure! While I'd imagine that there was not another request, *if you're curious what a particular browser actually does, use a tool to see what happens* (e.g. browser network/cache monitor, fiddler2 proxy, or wireshark tap).

Comment: I noticed that I was getting a 2nd http request for the same URI, but I guess I was just looking for an understanding of how that code is literally translated by the browser.

Answer (score 3):

It attempts to load the current page (`#`) as an image. This will almost always fail, as the current page is HTML, not an image.

The same thing will happen for all of the following HTML tags as well:

```
<img src="?"> (more or less)

<img src="">

<img> (under some browsers!)
```

Comment: Thx a lot!  This is what I was looking for.  This little bug costed me 2 hours of digging!  Is this kind of weird value stuff documented somewhere?  Or do you end up just finding out about it through experience?

Comment: What do you mean by weird? The # char in Url's is part of the Uri standard and used to indicate a location inside the page, a named anchor, so that you can get the browser to scroll down to the relevant part of a page directly. The weird part would be to use it in an image tag since it will probably never work in any intended way.

Comment: It's not necessarily HTML. The server could use the HTTP accept header to know whether the browser was expecting HTML or an image and serve content appropriately.

Comment: @DavidMartensson, yeah that's exactly what I mean, using # as the src in an image tag.